# Ubuntu 18.04 : nmbd service will not start

Tags: 18.04, samba

I had Samba up and running and it stopped working. The problem is that the NMBD service will not start up. If I issue `systemctl status nmbd.service` I get 
`Status: "nmbd: No local IPv4 non-loopback interfaces available, waiting for interface..."`

If I issue the `ifconfig` command I get back (abridged for space):

`eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu1500
.
.
.
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536`

I don't understand. Googling hasn't helped.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 8):

Check `smb.conf` and see if you got this:

```
interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
```

If so you may wanna change `eth0` to any working NIC port that would show up with `ip link`.  For me, changing it to:

```
interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 enp1s0
```

works wonder.  Only need to restart `nmdb` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have no ipv4 address at the time nmbd is starting up. This could happen, for example, if your network is wireless and only connected after you login on a desktop.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1731502 for details.

Comment: Andreas: Thanks much for your answer. However, the box is connected via wire directly to the router. I can connect to the shared drives but I cannot perform any operations on them.

Comment: `ip -4 addr` shows otherwise.